# How to store Ajax Return value into variable after clicking the Submit button

Tags: forms

I have created form with fields of State and City. After selecting the state appropriate city records will be loaded into city field till now working fine but after clicking the submit button I am not able to store city value into variable called $data1. Please guide me how to get it city value

```
function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) 
{
$form['state1']= array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('State'),
  '#options' =>$options_state,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => '_ajaxfunction',
    'wrapper' => 'divaroundseconddropdown'
  ),
);

$form['city_element_wrapper'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="divaroundseconddropdown">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

}
```

Ajax Function

```
 function _ajaxfunction($form, $form_state) 

    { 

$key = !empty($form_state['values']['state1']) ? $form_state['values']['state1'] : 1;

  $query_city=db_select('city', 'c');
  $query_city->fields('c',array('District_Code','District_Name','State_Code'));
  $query_city->condition('State_Code', $key, '=');

  $query_city->orderBy('District_Name','ASC');
  $city_results = $query_city->execute();
  $options_city = array();


  foreach ($city_results as $city_record)
{
    // This is correct.
    $options_city[$city_record->District_Code]=t($city_record->District_Name);
}

    $form['city_element_wrapper']['city']= array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('District'),
        '#options' => $options_city,
        '#required' => TRUE,);

    return $form['city_element_wrapper']; 
    }
```

Now I am trying to store the value of what I have selected in City into $data1 variable but I am not able to store it, Please guide me how to store

```
function form_test_custom_form_submit($form, $form_state){
    $data1 = $form_state['values']['city_element_wrapper']['city'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `$form['city']` form input creation into your `form_test_form` function otherwise it's considered tampering with the form, so the values will get taken out.

```
function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) {
  $form['state1']= array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('State'),
    '#options' =>$options_state,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_ajaxfunction',
      'wrapper' => 'divaroundseconddropdown'
    ),
  );

  $form['city_element_wrapper'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="divaroundseconddropdown">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  // If there's a "State" value set, then we create the City dropdown
  if (isset($form_state['values']['state1']) && !empty($form_state['values']['state1'])) {
    $form['city_element_wrapper']['city'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('District'),
      '#options' => $options_city,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
  }

  return $form;
}
```

Now the callback becomes a simple return of the relevant element:

```
function _ajaxfunction($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['city_element_wrapper']; 
}
```

Finally check the values of $form_state['values'] in your submit handler:

```
function form_test_custom_form_submit($form, $form_state){
  var_dump($form_state['values']);
  die();
}
```

Comment: In ajax function I trying to get appropriate city records under state. so how should I sent that records to form? please check my ajax function

Comment: Well you do that same query in the `form_test_form` function inside the `if` statement right?

Comment: as per my code city records are displaying but If I run the code inside the form_test_form, it is not showing anything

Comment: Debug. If the exact same code that works in `_ajaxfunction` doesn't work in `form_test_form` then there's something wrong with your code or the way you copy/pasted it. I can't help you with that.